# How to make a bootable USB drive from Install OS X El Capitan.app?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, usb, bootable-disk

I wish to upgrade from Snow Leopard (10.6.8) to anything higher.

Disk Utilities repair says the disk needs to be repaired.  So, I need to boot onto something other than the boot drive to run disk utilities.

I downloaded El Capitan from the App Store.  It appears to be an install app.  I tried [diskmakerx](http://diskmakerx.com), but it requires 10.7 or higher.  Not sure how to make a bootable image from the install app in Applications.

I can't use OS X Recovery, that also requires 10.7 or higher.

[These directions](http://www.maciverse.com/install-os-x-snow-leopard-from-usb-flash-drive.html) require the DVD media, which my parents likely never had.

All the [directions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/126092/how-to-create-a-10-6-8-recovery-cd-not-clone-of-the-os-or-install-environment) [I've](http://news.softpedia.com/news/How-to-Create-a-Bootable-Mac-OS-X-USB-Disk-214329.shtml) found for bootable USBs require a disk image.

Any options?

**Edit 1**: I created a USB drive using [these directions](http://www.macworld.com/article/2056561/how-to-make-a-bootable-mavericks-install-drive.html), "Option 2: Use Disk Utility."  I modified a bit (El Capitan instead of Yosemite, got the BaseImage.dmg by copying and using xattr to remove the invisible bit, ..), but I have a USB key with "Mac OS Extended" format and 7.8G of stuff on it.

When I boot up holding down the option key, it doesn't show any menu to choose where to boot from, it just ignores my USB drive.  When I open the "Startup Disk" system preferences dialog, it does not show the USB drive (even though it is mounted).  It is plugged directly into this mac mini, not through a hub or keyboard.

I looked around for related questions (e.g., [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/120824/macbook-pro-not-booting-off-os-x-mavericks-usb-drive)), and found nothing relevant.

Any idea of how to debug a USB drive being ignored upon (Snow Leopard) startup?

Answer (score 3):

(From [OS X Daily](http://osxdaily.com/2015/09/30/create-os-x-el-capitan-boot-install-drive/))

You'll need an 8 GB or larger USB Drive. Remember, it will be erased, so backup any important files.

Use the following command in **Terminal** (assuming the **Install OS X El Capitan** app is in `/Applications`, which where the App Store installs it by default)

Also make note of the USB Volume Label and use its name in the command below in place of: `<USB_Volume_Name>`

```
sudo /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ El\ Capitan.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume "/Volumes/<USB_Volume_Name>" --applicationpath /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ El\ Capitan.app --nointeraction
```

Comment: Thanks for the ref. As described in the article, that produces an error "Failed to start erase of disk due to error (-9999,0)." before 10.9. I am trying the "Disk Utility" method in the article.

Comment: @IronCraftMan your answer is valid *only* for OS X 10.7+. It doesn't work on OS X 10.6. On Snow Leopard, the only way to create a bootable USB key of newer version of the OS X installer is by using Disk Utility.