# Debug why USB drive is ignored as a bootable device?

Tags: snow-leopard, usb, startup

I created a USB drive with 'El Capitan' on it, as described [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/209330/how-to-make-a-bootable-usb-drive-from-install-os-x-el-capitan-app), which uses mostly [these directions](http://www.macworld.com/article/2056561/how-to-make-a-bootable-mavericks-install-drive.html), "option 2: Use Disk Utility."

I now have a USB key with "Mac OS Extended" format and 7.8G of stuff on it.

When I boot up (Snow Leopard) holding down the option key, it doesn't show any menu to choose where to boot from, it just ignores my USB drive. When I open the "Startup Disk" system preferences dialog, it does not show the USB drive (even though it is mounted). It is plugged directly into this mac mini, not through a hub or keyboard.

I looked around for related questions (e.g., [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/162705/macbook-pro-not-detecting-bootable-usb-with-yosemite)), and found nothing relevant.

**Edit 1**: This is a mac mini (model identifier "Macmini3,1") with an Intel Core 2 Duo running 10.6.8 (snow leopard).

Comment: I may have had the problem described here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/188584/22654 (wrong partition type). Trying..

Comment: It would help, too, if we knew the model & year of your Mac. Macs that came with Superdrives can be more than difficult to get to boot from USB.

Comment: @Tetsujin Added, thanks. I don't know how to tell year, tho.

Comment: [Everymac](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/mac_mini/specs/mac-mini-core-2-duo-2.0-early-2009-nvidia-specs.html) can always find a machine by its code number, so that makes yours an 09... which does have a Superdrive. That may be your stumbling block; I've followed every guide I've ever found to try boot an 09 Mac from USB - never succeeded yet. Wish you better luck than I ;)

Comment: Yikes! Thanks for the information, but that is a bummer.